# Limit user on ftp

Tags: ftp, cpanel, web-hosting

I got this 1tera web host but I only use 10mb.
I'm planning to rent out a folder on my public_html to others where they can use FTP to upload their web files. The problem is I don't know how to limit them from accessing my own public html.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a FTP account using Cpanel, you can create a folder inside public_html and this FTP account will be able to access this folder only, no other folder inside public_html. You can set a folder outside public_html too

[image]